# Mathematical representation of large numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math

I am attempting to write a function which takes a large number as input (upwards of 800 digits long) and returns a simple formula of no complex math as a string.

By simple math, I mean just **numbers** with **+,-,*,/,^** and **()** as needed.

`'4^25+2^32' = giveMeMath(1125904201809920); // example`

Any language would do. I can refactor it, just looking for some help with the logic.

Bonus. The shorter the output the better. Processing time is important. Also, mathematical accuracy is a must.

Update:
to clarify, all input values will be positive integers (no decimals)

Comment: Is there some criterion that you need the formula to use? There are infnitely many expressions that will evaluate to a given number.

Comment: Lisp is great for dealing with large numbers. If you want an "elegant" representation of a number, you could compute a bunch of different representations using separate, complicated algorithms, then choose the shortest one.

Comment: Your problem sounds similar to compressing a large number of bits.  I would look into how common compression algorithms work.

Comment: Is your intention to be able to shorten the length of the representation of the number?

Comment: @kindall that is right. I don't really care the particular formula it spits out, just that it be as short as possible & equals the numeric input. As mikesamuel mentioned this is for a compression of sorts

Comment: @gnibbler pretty much. I rarely expect to take the data back to "numeric" state once in the "equation" state

Comment: Do you want a representation that is **provably** the shortest possible ASCII representation of an integer (in terms of number of characters), or will you settle for just "a good deal shorter"?

Comment: @conductr, you won't be able to achieve compression for arbitrary numbers. Multiplication and addition are not going to give you any compression - only exponentation, and you can only apply that for a relatively small fraction of numbers.

Comment: @gnibbler you are right. I know the `^` exponent will be heavily used to achieve abbreviated magnitude. The less magnitude operands, **+,-,*,/** will primarily serve to obtain specificity. As in my example, I start with a large number `4^25` then add the smaller `2^32` to arrive at the exact input.

Comment: The question might be related to [Waring's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) that asks how to represent integer numbers as sums of powers s^k for fixed k, or a variant of it.

Comment: Have a closer look at compression methods and computational complexity (e.g. Kolmogorov complexity). If you try to compress all possible numbers no matter what method you choose, the same amount of inflation as deflation will be present. I.e. some numbers will get longer and some shorter and in total it cancels out. The only way to do real compression is to assume a subset of all numbers and make assumptions on properties of that subset (e.g. the entropy). Only in that case compression is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt in Python:

```
def give_me_math(n): 

    if n % 2 == 1:
        n = n - 1  # we need to make every odd number even, and add back one later
        odd = 1
    else:
        odd = 0
    exps = []

    while n > 0:
        c = 0
        num = 0
        while num <= n/2:
            c += 1
            num = 2**c

        exps.append(c)    
        n = n - num
    return (exps, odd)
```

Results:

```
>>> give_me_math(100)
([6, 5, 2], 0)  #2**6 + 2**5 + 2**2 + 0 = 100

>>> give_me_math(99)
([6, 5, 1], 1)  #2**6 + 2**5 + 2**1 + 1 = 99

>>> give_me_math(103) 
([6, 5, 2, 1], 1) #2**6 + 2**5 + 2**2 + 2**1 + 1 = 103
```

I believe the results are accurate, but I am not sure about your other criteria.

Edit:

Result: Calculates in about a second.

```
>>> give_me_math(10**100 + 3435)
([332, 329, 326, 323, 320, 319, 317, 315, 314, 312, 309, 306, 304, 303, 300, 298, 295, 294, 289, 288, 286, 285, 284, 283, 282, 279, 278, 277, 275, 273, 272, 267, 265, 264, 261, 258, 257, 256, 255, 250, 247, 246, 242, 239, 238, 235, 234, 233, 227, 225, 224, 223, 222, 221, 220, 217, 216, 215, 211, 209, 207, 206, 203, 202, 201, 198, 191, 187, 186, 185, 181, 176, 172, 171, 169, 166, 165, 164, 163, 162, 159, 157, 155, 153, 151, 149, 148, 145, 142, 137, 136, 131, 127, 125, 123, 117, 115, 114, 113, 111, 107, 106, 105, 104, 100, 11, 10, 8, 6, 5, 3, 1], 1)
```

800 digit works fast too:

```
>>> give_me_math(10**800 + 3452)
```

But the output is too long to post here, which is OPs concern of course.

Time complexity here is 0(ln(n)), so it is pretty efficient.

Comment: It's about large numbers (100 digits was the statement) so I assume this won't work.

Comment: @akavall this is a great start which I can add to, surely the next step is increasing the base which will reduce the output.

Comment: @conductr yes, I think the next step is playing around with different combinations of bases to shrink the output.

Answer (score 2):

I think the entire problem can be recast to a [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) problem on the binary representation of the long integer.

For example, take the following number:

```
17976931348623159077293051907890247336179769789423065727343008115773
26758055009631327084773224075360211201138798713933576587897688144166
22492847430639474110969959963482268385702277221395399966640087262359
69162804527670696057843280792693630866652907025992282065272811175389
6392184596904358265409895975218053120L
```

This looks fairly horrendous. In binary, though:

```
>>> bin(_)
'0b11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000'
```

Which is about 500 ones, followed by 500 zeroes. This suggests an expression like:

```
2**1024 - 2**512
```

Which is how I obtained the large number in the first place.

If there are no significantly long runs in the binary representation of the integer, this won't work well at all. `101010101010101010....` is the worst case.

Comment: I did some brief digging around with this binary method and this was the problem I kept running into also, in practice (with random numbers) long runs are rare enough that this becomes impractical

Comment: Arbitrary random numbers are, by **definition**, incompressible. An `n`-bit random number contains about `n` bits of entropy - you can't compress it any further.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you should take a look at the `BigDecimal` class in java.math package.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Are you saying there is a build in method which already does what I need?

Comment: BigDecimal has a lot of the operations you are asking for, but you'll have to write a parser to map your language to those methods.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, one thing I can say is I don't tink you can have a literal that big on your source code and expect the result to be accurate unless is a string literal. On the other hand, if the kind of function you want extracts the factors of your number randomly then it's kind of weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to have a look at

1. The [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) library (The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library) for performing the arithmetics
2. Take a look at [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). The link redirects to Wikipedia which should give probably a good overview. However to be a bit more scientific:

   - [Integer factorization](http://www.connellybarnes.com/documents/factoring.pdf) (PDF) by [Daniel Bernstein](http://cr.yp.to/djb.html)  of the University of Illinois
   - [Integer Factorization Algorithms](http://www.connellybarnes.com/documents/factoring.pdf) (PDF) by Connelly Barnes of the Department of Physics, Oregon State University